# How do I include Entity Framework as part of my Azure Worker Role deployment?

Tags: entity-framework, azure, azure-worker-roles

I'm migrating my code to an Azure Worker Role and am using Entity Framework 4.1 for database access.
On Azure my Worker Role crashes as it doesn't find Entity Framework 4.1 to be installed on the machine.

- Is there a simple way to have Entity Framework 4.1 is installed on the Worker Role? (without invoking silent installs via a batch script)
- What is the default Entity Framework version that comes with Azure Compute? (if it's higher than 4.1 I'll just upgrade my code)

Note: I tried marking my EntityFramework and System.Data.Entity references as 'Copy Local' but to no avail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows Azure instances do not come with any version of EF installed by default.  All they have is a basic install of .net (4 with OS family 2, 4.5 with OS family 3) any thing else you want to use you have to provide. You shouldn't need to do an install of EF it's quite possible that there is another reference that you need to set to copy local.  EF 5 is now available as a Nuget package, perhaps if you added that VS might be smart enough to sort it out for you.

Comment: Upgrading to Entity Framework 5.0 did the trick. Visual Studio was indeed smart enough to sort it out once installed as an Nuget package. Thanks!

Comment: Good call on using the Nuget package. Copying all output to local worked for me, but Nuget is a all around better solution. Just a reminder, be aware of any affected dependencies.